# Apple App Store: Create app page for upcoming app

Tags: ios, itunes, ios-appstore, app-store-connect

From yesterday's iPhone 7 release event, Super Mario Run by Nintendo will be available on iOS soon. After searching same on iTunes, I found out that its iTunes page is available with **NOTIFY** button instead of the regular GET button.

How to do that? What is provision provided by Apple to show app's iTune page without actually uploading app ?

[image]

Comment: I'd guess the provision is "Work with us so we can advertise this at the Keynote & in exchange you can get this fab new way to put your app on the Store."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notify is a feature created by Apple which appears to be solely for their Nintendo app launch partnership at this current time. It's not available for general developer program members yet and it is unclear if/when it will be available in iTunes Connect.

> The feature is currently only for Super Mario Run as far as we can tell. Whether it will apply across the entire app store is yet to be determined. It's also unlike the "Pre-order" button from the music and film sections of the iTunes store, since it doesn't give you the option to purchase the content ahead of time.

<sup>Source: http://www.cnet.com/news/new-itunes-notifications-will-tell-you-when-mario-is-live/</sup>